# How to get the duration of an audio file in flutter?

Tags: audio, flutter

I am trying to get the duration of an audio file and set it to a `String`. I am using `flutter_sound` plugin to play the sound. `onPlayerStateChanged` listen has duration but I don't know how to use it to set a `String` to duration value without playing the sound.

The main aim is I want to select an audio file which has a Max length of 20 sec. Can anyone please help me solve it?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use:

```
audioplayers: any then await audioPlayer.play(audioFile.path, isLocal: true);
duration = await audioPlayer.getDuration();
```

Comment: audioplayers: any
then
await audioPlayer.play(audioFile.path, isLocal: true);
then this link return a duration
int duration = await audioPlayer.getDuration();